# Android: How to use "adb shell wm" to simulate other devices

Tags: android, adb

So I bought a Nexus 10 for development and was super excited by the prospect of being able to simulate other devices using the "adb shell wm" command, with its size, density, and overscan subcommands.

However, I've had a few problems making this work. I'd like to see if anyone else has encountered/overcome these. For the sake of this discussion, let's say I'm trying to simulate a typical phone, running the following:

```
adb shell wm size 800x480
adb shell wm density 240
adb shell wm overscan reset
```

First, setting the size messes up the menu bar. In portrait mode, only some of the buttons will be present and at the wrong scale, and in landscape mode, the menu bar is completely missing. In fact, even after you reset everything, it's still missing until you restart the device. Any workaround for this?

Secondly, what does the overscan command do? I can't find any documentation for it anywhere.

Thirdly, is there any way to make the device render the screen using 1 pixel of the new size to 1 pixel of the physical screen? That is to say, if I set the size to 800x480, I'd like to see the new screen take up exactly that much space. Instead, what seems to happen is the 800x480 screen is stretched so that the longest side just fits on the physical display. I suspect that overscan might be the answer, but when I tried to set it to 0,0,800,480, it permanently hung my system and I had to reset to the factory image to recover.

Finally, is there any way to cause the tablet to simulate a phone in terms of what happens to the menu bar during an orientation change? On a tablet, the menu bar goes to new bottom of the screen, but on a phone, it stays where it is.

I like this device so far, but if I could just get this device simulation stuff working, I'd love it! Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Brian did you have this problem where wm size displays portrait in a landscape, wasting so much screenspace?

Comment: @pt123 My app is a landscape app, so I didn't try that.

Comment: didn't it swap it other way for landscape, I forgot to link my question it has a diagram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086099/adb-set-display-size-is-incorrectly-displaying-portrait-using-landscape thansk

Comment: Does it work any differently if you swap the dimensions? E.g., 720x1200 instead of 1200x720? If not, I'd say that yes, I agree that it's a waste of screen real estate, but the only thing this feature of the OS is really good for is ballpark verification of layout, because the image is going to be horrendously stretched or squashed any way you cut it. So use it for that. If you need more pixel-perfect verification, you'll have to test on emulators or the real target devices.

Comment: wow thanks it worked, if you go my question and reply that as an answer I can approve it and you will get the deserved points for it. Now with this working the 7inch tablet is displaying a 4.5 inch screen quite well. This could be useful. I find with emulators it's difficult to make your app touch friendly, right size buttons and spacing.

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it worked. I've added the answer to your post as well. Thanks!

Comment: I get  error `/system/bin/sh: wm: not found`. Why? please look at my question in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30839523/779408

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out enough of this to be useful. I will attempt to answer each of the questions I raised in my original post. Then I'll share a few other things I've learned about how to use this effectively.

- Is there any way to avoid messing up the menu bar when at the home screen?

Not that I've discovered, and changing the settings seems to have a cumulative effect that will usually royally screw up the home screen until you restart the device. However, you can usually at least unlock the device, which is enough to be useful. The key is to start your app first, then adjust the size and density while already running it. Simply press the power button to turn off the screen, adjust the size and density as you like, then power the screen back on, unlock, and you're app will be running properly at the new size and density.

- What does the overscan command do?

I've found only oblique references to this, but the best I can determine, it's for TVs or other displays where not all of the screen is guaranteed to be usable/visible. I don't think it really applies to a regular phone or tablet.

- Is there any way to make the device render the screen using 1 pixel of the new size to 1 pixel of the physical screen?

Not that I've discovered. But it probably doesn't matter. I think the main point of using the adb shell wm commands is to test layout, not to see pixel-perfect graphics. (And believe me, what you get is the farthest thing possible from pixel-perfect.)

- Is there any way to cause the tablet to simulate a phone in terms of what happens to the menu bar during an orientation change?

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but for me, the menu bar behaves in bizarre and unpredictable ways. Sometimes it's massive, sometimes it's just missing. Don't count on being able to use it. Yes, this sucks. Someone please chime in if there's a solution to this.

- So how do I use "adb shell wm" effectively?

I'm not sure why, but it took me a little while to grasp this. That's probably because when I first started this, my mind was not accustomed to the Android way of thinking about things. But it's actually pretty simple.

First, set the size you want in pixels. For this discussion, let's say we're going to use 1024x600.

Next, set the DPI. But what should you set it to?

That's the tricky part (well, the part I didn't get at first). When you set the DPI, you're setting the other half of the equation that will determine the dimensions in DP of the virtual application space, which the app will use to render itself. (Duh, I know, but I at first thought the specified DPI would be used mainly to select resources, which indeed it also does.)

Let's take a look at the consequences of using various densities with a screen size of 1024x600.

First, keep in mind that

```
dp = px * (160 / dpi)
```

That means if we specify our dpi at 160, the app will believe that the available space is 1024dp x 600dp. If instead we use 240, that changes to a meager 683dp x 400 dp, and conversely, if we use 120, we get an impressive 1365 dp x 800 dp. Set it to 80, and now you're rocking 2048dp x 1200dp.

The counter-intuitive part is realizing that specifying a low density results an image that appears like what you might see in an ultra-hi-res monitor -- everything is tiny. But that's because the app is now treating the same physical space as though it were a very large size *in dp.*

So going back to the example of a density of 80, we have a virtual area of 2048dp x 1200dp, but it is being scrunched onto whatever sized physical screen you're actually using. Since 160dp is supposed to be about 1 inch, that would be an almost otherworldly tablet with a width of 12.8 inches. But that entire thing is scrunched down to the actual size of your tablet, making your generously sized 30dp text appear pretty puny.

Maybe I'm just the slowest kid in the room, but it took me a while to really grok this. I hope it helps someone else out there.

Comment: when I run `adb shell wm density 240` i get error: `/system/bin/sh: wm: not found`. Why?

My device is rooted!

Comment: @breceivemail : wm is available only in JellyBean 4.3 and above. You can use am display-size and am display-density instead, in pre-4.3 devices

Comment: The bottom 20% of my Nexus 4 doesn't work. I use: `wm overscan 0,0,0,210` to have android WM not draw anything in that area so that I can operate all the drawn areas fully again..

Comment: @Brian Rak Correction: px = dp * (dpi / 160), source: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the excellent guide.i am just trying to use it for different use case, where some of the apps on my devices should run with specific dpi and when those apps exits dpi should be reset back to what is defined by manufacturer. Do you see any issues doing this way?

Answer (score 1):

I guess overscan is setting the space of the screen ("the margin") that is not used. Try with something like *adb shell wm overscan 200,200,200,200* start an app and you will see the difference. In Home the difference is not so clear.

If this is really useful in combination with size and density I don't know. I did some tests but no useful result. It is a little complicated (?) to see what values to use...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It helps confirm what I was seeing. I think it renders part of the screen unusable, which could be useful for CRTs and other monitors where not all of the screen is guaranteed to be visible. What I don't understand is that it seems to actually take space out of the specified app size. So if you set the app size to 800x600 but set an overscan of 200,0,0,0, your actual interface is only 600x600. I guess if you really wanted to use overscan, you'd have to just add the overscanned amount to the original size dimensions.

Comment: I also use a Nexus 10 for testing apps on various screen sizes. I think adb shell wm is useful. The "physical screen size" is not correct (it is streched) and the navigation bar is corrupt (and also Home screen) as you said. But the relative size of the components seem to be correct and you can see if things fit on the screen etc. The AVD is extremely slow simulating tablets on an old PC...

Comment: I noticed that overscan throws fragments into a frenzy. What could be the reason? Try setting overscan and open apps like gmail, and more space than the overscan area remains white.

Comment: @aravindsagar: Yes, I see that too! Perhaps its a GMail bug? I also notice that it doesn't happen when I hit reply to any email, and pull keyboard down..

Comment: @Thrustmaster : I noticed that in multiple apps, like Inbox, as well as an app that I developed. The common thing that I noticed in all those apps is that they have nav drawers. Maybe it's a problem with drawer layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into the "reset to the factory image" crash menu after trying to change the device's resolution, here is how I solved it without factory reset (multiple hard reboots would always lead to the same "blue screen" menu):

- connect computer to phone through usb (wifi connection won't work since phone rebooted)
- send back the adb command to set the original dimensions (`adb shell wm <width>x<height>`), between the moment the phone is starting and the moment it crashes (you've got to be fast)