# ADB set display-size is incorrectly displaying portrait using landscape

Tags: android, adb, screen-orientation

I am using the adb feature to set the screensize to see how the app looks on smaller screens. 
using the command :

```
adb shell am display-size 1200x720
```

in 4.3 the command is

```
adb shell wm size 1200x720
```

But it is seems to be behaving stupidly as it displays portrait view of the app in landscape view of the device. [image: diagram]

Leaving so much screen not used and result is a smaller looking device than need be. The device is the Nexus 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just swap the order of the dimensions. So instead of 1200x720, use 720x1200. That should do it for you.