# Testing multiple screen resolutions

Tags: android, testing

I have created an app that according to a user has a problem on a certain device. Obviously, I do not have that device, but the problem seems straightforward: the UI is too large for its screen.

To correctly fix this, I want to be able to test the entire app in a smaller screen size. I have a Galaxy Nexus, which has a nice large screen. I was wondering if there is some app or tool that I can run an app on my Nexus, but in a smaller resolution. This way, I could test my UI designs without the need of having all kinds of devices.

Comment: Have you tried the emulator? If so, what about the emulator did not meet your needs?

Comment: I haven't tried on this app. But when I have in the past, I found it slow and unusable. Also, I am using the WiFi scanning, which I reckon is not available in the emulator.

Comment: It is definitely slow. Unfortunately I am not aware of a method of forcing a different display density on a physical device. If possible, I would try to recreate the problem on the emulator with some mock data to avoid the WiFi scanning issue.

Comment: Try genymotion.com It uses hardware acceleration by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **`adb shell wm display-size`** to teach your device to run at a different display size, or **`adb shell wm display-density`** to have it emulate a different density. Note that the `wm` bit is for Android 4.3 and higher; Android 4.0-4.2 would use `am` instead.

See [Android: How to use "adb shell wm" to simulate other devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500611/android-how-to-use-adb-shell-wm-to-simulate-other-devices).

Comment: Great, this was exactly what I was looking for. I got a missing `WAKE_LOCK` exception, but that was because I had the screen on while trying.

Comment: @CommonsWare - the G+ post is no longer available. Is there any alternate url for this article.

Comment: @Tarun: I do not know of any, sorry.