# Error on running "adb shell wm density 240" for changing Android device density

Tags: android, resize, adb, screen-size

I want to resize the screen on Android device. When I run the following commands:

`adb shell wm density 240`

or

`adb shell wm size 800x480`

I get error:

`/system/bin/sh: wm: not found`.

Why? How can I resolve that?

I should mention that my device is rooted and its model is `Asus transformer TF101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it to:

`adb shell am display-size 800x480`

and it worked

Comment: With `am display-size 800x480` I get **error: unknown command 'display-size'**. I also tried `wm size 800x480` but I get **no command 'wm' found**. So what could I try? (I am on Android 8.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

wm (Window Manager) is not available on Jelly Bean and older devices.
for pre jelly bean use

```
adb shell am display-density 240
```

or

```
adb shell am display-size 800x480
```